# Using conditional to select different set of widgets in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am following Angela Yu's introductory course on Flutter and extending the Quizzler project for personal challenge. At the end of a quiz, I give the user a chance to start again (show the first question screen) or to end the game (show a "goodbye" screen). I have this basic structure:

```
class _QuizPageState extends State<QuizPage> {
  Widget selectContents() {
    // getGameState() reads a boolean flag; false means user is quitting
    // but a change from true to false is only detected
    // when main.dart is saved in the IDE.
    print('Game State: --------> ${quizBrain.getGameState()}');
    return (quizBrain.getGameState()) ? QuizContents() : GoodbyeScreen();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: selectContents(),
    );
  }
}
```

This does not work. When the user opts to end the quiz, the choice does not register and the last screen of `QuizContents` remains visible. When I go into the IDE and simply save `main.dart`, the flag somehow updates (and the `print` statement now reports the right value for the game state) and `GoodbyeScreen()` appears in the simulator.

This problem has many versions and suggestions on StackOverflow. I have tried all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49713189/how-to-use-conditional-statement-within-child-attribute-of-a-flutter-widget-cen) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57075342/flutter-how-to-conditionally-add-a-widget), including:

- putting the ternary operator directly as a child to the `Container`
- using a `Builder` widget instead of the `Container`
- putting the `selectContents()` function inside and outside the `build()` method of `_QuizPageState`
- using `if/else` cascade inside an anonymous function as a child to the `Container`
- ...etc

None of these have worked and the behaviour remains the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a state management problem. You haven't included where `quizBrain` is saved, but if it's in `_QuizPageState`, calling `setState` when you change boolean flag should fix the problem, otherwise the widget is never rebuilt.

The reason saving in your IDE updates the value is because Flutter performs a hot reload and rebuilds some (maybe all) widgets.

There are many other state management methods, apart from `setState`. An interesting read is [Simple app state management](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/simple). Your choice depends on the complexity of your app, but I would imagine in this case, `setState` should be enough.